# What should a lua iterator factory return in case of nothing to iterate

Tags: lua, luajit

I am implementing a lua iterator and I wonder what the iterator factory (the function that creates the closure which is used to iterate over the iteratable, see `list_iter` on http://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html ) should return in case of nothing to iterate.

E.g. lets say I would implement a list type and my list object just would not have any entries at all. So I would suppose that the body `...` of `for i in myiterator do ... end` 
is just never visited and the script execution continues as if nothing happened.

At the moment I return `nil` and Lua(jit) complains about `attempt to call a nil value`. The same happens if I do not return a return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a closure that returns `nil` like this:

```
function nil_iter()
  return function() return nil end
end
```